# How to display datatable value into text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I want to show my datatable value into text box with including headers
I tried something like this not sure its correct or not ?

```
private void Button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox5.Text = string.Empty;
            if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
            {

                string strSQLConn = "Server =" + textBox1.Text + "; Initial Catalog =" + textBox2.Text + "; User ID =" + textBox3.Text + "; Password = " + textBox4.Text + ";";
                SqlConnection SQLConn = new SqlConnection(strSQLConn);
                SQLConn.Open();
                foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
                {
                    DataRowView row = item as DataRowView;
                    SqlCommand SQLCmd = new SqlCommand("select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, IS_NULLABLE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = '" + row["Table_Name"] + "' ", SQLConn);
                    SQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLCmd);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    Da.Fill(dt);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        textBox5.Text = dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                        textBox5.Text = dt.Rows[0]["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString();
                        textBox5.Text = dt.Rows[0]["DATA_TYPE"].ToString();
                        textBox5.Text = dt.Rows[0]["CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH"].ToString();
                        textBox5.Text = dt.Rows[0]["IS_NULLABLE"].ToString();

                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: How can you not be sure? Have you tried it yet? What's the output?

Comment: i am getting my table all rows and column in dt,  but unable to display into text box output is only :  NO

Comment: `textBox5.Text` will always be `dt.Rows[0]["IS_NULLABLE"].ToString()` cause it's `=` instead of `+=`

Comment: this is my table structure TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS_NULLABLE
tbl_test ID int NULL NO
tbl_test Name varchar 50 YES
tbl_test Row varchar 50 YES

Comment: when i added = instead of += now its showing some more record like tbl_dataIDintNO

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to append instead of overriding the text. Therefore,

```
textBox5.Text = dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + ", ";
textBox5.Text += dt.Rows[0]["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString()+ ", ";
textBox5.Text += dt.Rows[0]["DATA_TYPE"].ToString()+ ", ";
textBox5.Text += dt.Rows[0]["CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH"].ToString()+ ", ";
textBox5.Text += dt.Rows[0]["IS_NULLABLE"].ToString();
```

To go through all rows

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    textBox5.Text = dt.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + ", ";
    textBox5.Text += dt.Rows[i]["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString()+ ", ";
    textBox5.Text += dt.Rows[i]["DATA_TYPE"].ToString()+ ", ";
    textBox5.Text += dt.Rows[i]["CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH"].ToString()+ ", ";
    textBox5.Text += dt.Rows[i]["IS_NULLABLE"].ToString();
}
```

Moreover, I suggest to scope your connection, command and adapter in `using`(so system can close/dispose them automatically) and use 
`SqlParameter` instead of string concatenation(to prevent potential SQL injection)

```
using (SqlConnection SQLConn = new SqlConnection(strSQLConn))
{
    SQLConn.Open();
    foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
        DataRowView row = item as DataRowView;
        using (SqlCommand SQLCmd = new SqlCommand("select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, IS_NULLABLE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @tableName ", SQLConn))
        {
            SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("tableName", row["Table_Name"]);
            using (SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLCmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                Da.Fill(dt);
                // rest of the code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can retrieve columns from `DataTable.Columns` and if you too want to attach to the `TextBox` then sample as below

```
textBox5.Text += string.Join(",", dt.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Select(col => col.ColumnName));
```

Comment: much better then previous but still its showing only one row and in my respective table has 3 rows and its exclude my headers i want my headers also

Comment: @NitsPatel use loop so that index will iterate in your rows

Comment: @蕭為元  please help

Comment: how to select Header also ??

Comment: @NitsPatel I don't really understand. Do you mean select column names as a `datarow`? But why bother since you already knew all of them?

Comment: i have to display actual value along with headers so .

Comment: same as data grid ?? i know as it is not possible in text box

Comment: I add the way to get columns and if you have further question you should probably open another question post cause we are a bit out of the original topic now.